# Is it possible to load image using windows absolute path in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

As the title says is it possible to load images from react using windows absolute path or do I really need to put my images in public folder of my react. I'm trying to preview my Pictures

Comment: it'a possible to use the absolute path on your local machine. I would'n because It won't work to deploy, while using your public folder always work you also can use your asset folder.

Comment: @guilhermevictorramalhonatal I wont deploy this project this is for personal use